# ko observable is not getting updated

Tags: knockout.js

I'm unable to create two-way binding with knockout observable. The data is getting initialized properly, but updating the value(x in UI) during a click function is where I'm finding difficulties. Any help would be greatfull, as I'm new to knockout making transition from angular for a client,
Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/govardhan_s92/abq9j5t4/1/

Thanks in advance.

Html:

```
<div class='liveExample'>
    <p data-bind="text:x,click:test()"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.x=ko.observable("");
    this.x = "something 1";
    this.test = function() {
        this.x = "something 2"
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you assign `this.x` to become a `ko.observable` (which makes it a *function reference* to the ko.observable function):

```
this.x = ko.observable("");
```

In the next line you tell `this.x` to *instead* become a regular string variable, which *overwrites* the `ko.observable` function reference:

```
this.x = "something1";
```

If you want to update an observable variable's value (remember: it's a function!), you need to pass it to the variable as a function argument rather than assigning the new value to the variable (which **overwrites** the observable):

```
this.x("something1");
```

Also, your click binding should be `click: test` not `click: test()` since otherwise you assign to the click handler whatever executing `text()` **returns**.

```
<p data-bind="text: x, click: test"></p>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abq9j5t4/2/)

Comment: I like your answer, because you don't only show right example(how it works), but you explaned why not worked(principle of knockout world).

Answer (score 1):

when you assign ko.observable() to x, this.x becomes a function which accepts the new value to be updated

You need to do this

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.x=ko.observable("");
    this.x("something 1");
    this.test = function() {
        this.x("something 2")
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```